# What is the class of Map<MyClassType1,Object>

Tags: java

I have to pass to a constructor the class of `Map<ClassType1,Object>`. if i pass `Map.class` only, I have an error. So I would like to know what's the class of `Map<MyClassType1,Object>` ?

```
public class GetSessionRequest extends SpiceRequest<Map<ClassType1, Object>> {

    private Client mClient;
    public GetSessionRequest(Class<Map<ClassType1, Object>> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }

    public GetSessionRequest(Client client) {
        super(/*What should I pass here. I can't pass Map.class*/); 
        mClient = client;
    }


    @Override
    public Map<ClassType1, Object> loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        Map<ClassType1, Object> map = mClient.getSession();
        return map;
    }

}
```

Comment: It is a class though. It all depends on what the constructor is expecting and doing (I assume it is a constructor of some other class). Can you add some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
public class T {
    public T(Class<Map<MyClassType1, Object>> cls) {
    }
}
```

But you'll need this instead:

```
public class T {
    public T(Class<? extends Map<MyClassType1, Object>> cls) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<MyClassType1, Object> m = new HashMap<MyClassType1, Object>();
        T t = new T(m.getClass());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map` is an interface. There are many implementations available for example `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

If it allows the map `interface`  the `method or constructor` can allow any [**implementation**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/map.html) of `Map interface`

Answer (score 0):

`Map` has no constructor, its an interface, you can use a `HashMap<ClassType1,Object>` or `TreeMap<ClassType1,Object>`

Answer (score 0):

Map<> is an interface just like the List<> and interface does not have constructor. You have to use HashMap, TreeMap or any class who implements the interface.